# How do I add File Attributed to When Making a file with FStream

Tags: c++, fstream

I found code that saves a BMP correctly with the following code...

```
char* bytes; // Created & populated using a different function...
DWORD size_of_bytes = 0; // Created & populated using a different function...
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(L"Test.bmp", GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
DWORD dwWritten = 0;
WriteFile(hFile, bytes, size_of_bytes, &dwWritten, NULL);
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

However, I want to save it using fstream... but when I do this the picture becomes deformed and some of it shows as static... I'm assuming it has something to do with these attributes:

> (GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS,
>   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL)

Is there anyway to set these attributes using fstream when writing to a file? Or is it messing up for another reason?

Comment: You're not going to get small distortions and such from those kind of attributes. As a guess, is your fstream operating in text mode instead of binary? That could lead to somewhat subtle problems.

Comment: I think the bug is the part that is not shown. Perhaps the bitmap does not properly handle the padding requirement

Comment: Please show your coding attempt to provide a [mre].

Comment: @TheUndeadFish that was the problem. Thanks!